# After automatic PuTTY login, getting only dollar sign as shell prompt in terminal

Tags: unix, batch-file, putty

When I am doing automatic PuTTY login from Windows bat file, after login command prompt is showing only dollar sign in UNIX terminal. But when I am doing manual login in PuTTY, after login, it is showing full directory name in UNIX terminal.

I am doing automatic PuTTY login this way:

```
putty.exe -ssh 172.1.5.166@somewhere.com -pw mypasswordforsomewherecom -m cmd.txt -t
```

In cmd.exe file there are some UNIX commands to run in remote computer:

```bsh
mkdir test
/n
sh
```

What I have observed that `.profile` of user is not executing when I am doing automatic PuTTY login. But `.profile` is executed when doing manual PuTTY login to the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is running the 'sh' shell, and the simple `$` prompt is completely normal for sh.

If your usual shell prompt includes more information, then you were probably using `bash` or `zsh`. (But it could also be 'tcsh' or 'fish' or something else.)

- Try changing your script's last command to `bash`.
- Try changing your script's last command to run `$SHELL`. (Literally just $SHELL.)
- Try adding the `-l` option to the command, to force the shell to run in "login mode".

Comment: when i use echo $SHELL, to get the value ,it prints   /usr/bin/sh

Comment: when i am using -l option ,error message is showing telling that -l requires argument

Comment: Add `-l` to `bash` commandline, not `plink` commandline.

Comment: problem is that if i use sh -l ,,,the putty screen is closed immediately, But if i use only sh putty screen is not closed immediately.But in the login shell it is showing only dollar.My requirement is that putty screen should not closed immediately and the  login shell should display full path ,not the dollar sign

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your default shell. Typically (as when I was dealing with this issue), you're probably looking for Bash. As the user (whom the shell is only display '$'), run:

```
sudo chsh <username> -s /bin/bash
```